# Undeletable directory with several subdirectories

Tags: filesystem, macos

I have noticed a folder on / called "Previous System". After checking that it did not have anything I need, I moved it to the trash. However, when emptying the trash, I get a "file in use" error.

When I attempt to use `rm` in the Terminal to perform the delete, this happens:

```
# rm -rf .Trash/Previous\ System
rm: .Trash/Previous System/private/tmp/coreutils20150822-26525-1gnqu7f/coreutils-8.24/confdir-14B---/<SNIP>confdir-14B---: No space left on device
<several "no space left on device" errors removed>
rm: .Trash/Previous System/private/tmp/coreutils20150822-26525-1gnqu7f/coreutils-8.24/confdir-14B---<SNIP>/confdir-14B---: Directory not empty
rm: .Trash/Previous System/private/tmp/coreutils20150822-26525-1gnqu7f/coreutils-8.24/confdir-14B---: Directory not empty
rm: .Trash/Previous System: Directory not empty
```

The unedited output shows an error for each 'confdir-14B---' recursion. They are directories, not symbolic links.

Free space is not an issue, `df -h` reports I have 56 GiB available.

Comment: I see that you found an answer that works, but I was going to suggest trying this after rebooting as soon as you can get a terminal window open or trying in Single User Mode as root.

Comment: @rubynorails while I didn't mention it, I did try deleting the directory in Single User Mode, and the same result occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here:
https://superuser.com/a/981772

Basically, `cd` to the start of the recursive folders, and repeatedly run

`for FILE in $(ls); do mv $FILE a; cd a; done`

This will rename the next folder to  "a" and `cd` into it. Eventually, this should reach the end of the recursion and/or allow deletion.

Comment: Did you already try?